# how to add dynamic field names by looking up a map in vector remap language?

Tags: datadog, vector-vrl

I am using Datadog vector to parse log line to json. I need to create the field name in the output json based on field mapping. The field mapping could change in future. For eg. the field mapping could be as follows:

- `username : uname` `ipAddress : ip` `source : device`

The values in the above mapping should be the field names in the output json. Trying to find a way in Vector Remap Language (VRL) to accomplish the above. Seeking help from experts.